# Why I can't update the value of an input tag putting in it the € character using JQuery? I obtain â‚¬ string instead €

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, html-encode

I am pretty new in JavaScript\JQuery and I have the following problem:

Into a JSP page (but I think that this is not so important the type of page...it is a page that contain HTML) I have this input tag having **id="saldoModale2"**:

```
<input id="saldoModale2" type="text" style="width: 25%" class="rightAlligned form-control" value='${progetto.impSal}' />
```

Then I have a JQuery script that, when the user click on a button, update the value of this input tag, in this way:

```
$("#saldoModale2").val('€');
```

So the previous line should only put the **€** character inside my input tag.

The problem is that instead see **€** in my input tag I obtain this strange value: **â‚¬**

The problem seems to be related to the **€** character because if I put the **$** by:

```
$("#saldoModale2").val('$');
```

it perfectly works.

The strangest thing is that I have also tryied to perform this replacment into a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/4720ek9g/1/ 
and here seems works fine. So I am asking if it could depend by some charset\encoding properties of the file that implement my page, or something like this.

Why? What am I missing? What is wrong?

Comment: UTF-8 encoding, probably? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp

Comment: @JeremyThille I have added into the <head> section but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The issue is to do with the character encoding of the page. Try using the unicode value for `€` instead:

```
$("#saldoModale2").val('\u20ac');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4720ek9g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add something like this to head section of your html?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I have added into the <head> section but I still have the same problem